# Internal usb device crash on reboot

Tags: drivers, usb

Internal usb device connected to the motherboard crashes on a reboot or shutdown/startup operation, only when I disconect the power cable and then reconect it and power on does the device appear and connect.
internal usb device: usb wifi adapter
before a reboot, I can detect the devicce perfectly and it is usale however after a reboot it is not connected.

I have tried using `usbreset` which can reastart the usb hub and also the device however after a reboot it does not show up and reastarting all of the devices listed in the above command will not make it appear.
the same is true for the `dmesg` and `lsusb` commands, where they detect the device as expected but do not after a reboot.

I have tried to use `modprobe` to reastart `uhci_hcd` and ehci_hcd however the linux kernel on my install is compiled with the above built in and not in a modular format to reastart/reset them.